# No matching distribution for virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

"Could not find the version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv ( from versions: )
No matching distribution found for virtualenv" is the error message when I try to install virtualenv on my  windows 10.

I have Googled it and followed several guide but no good result.

I have uninstalled and installed several lower versions of python, yet the same story.
I have been stocked for 6 days now trying to install django via pip.

I don't know what to do again.
Any true solution to my problem will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you install the virtual environment? is Python in your `PATH` variable? *(Also, this has nothing to do with mysql, so I removed that tag. If it was related, please specify how)*

Comment: did you try `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and then do your install again?  You might have a really old version of pip

Comment: If you are on python 3.3 or later then python already includes the venv module, running `py -m virtualenv env` at a command line (assuming python is installed as recommended) will create a virtual environment named **env**

Comment: @e.s.,You are correct,after upgrading the pip,i got it right

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Try this command before the virtualenvwrapper... command

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue when working with virtual environments. I fixed the issue after upgrading the pip and then installing virtual env.

pip: upgrade pip using below command:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

or

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

virtual env: install virtual env using the below command

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

this works fine for me

Comment: is this for windows?

Answer (score -2):

Please correct your spelling of `pip install virtualenvwrapper-win`.

I have also this problem with miss-spelling.