# Python2.7-pip not installing modules

Tags: pip, virtualenv

I can't install any modules in my python=2.7.

I am trying to create a new environvent on server of gpu which has already python2.7 installed in it

```
pip install virtualenv --user
```

```
Collecting virtualenv
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))': /simple/virtualenv/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))': /simple/virtualenv/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))': /simple/virtualenv/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))': /simple/virtualenv/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))': /simple/virtualenv/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for virtualenv
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410591/no-matching-distribution-for-virtualenv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PIP not working - proxy - Connection aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701622/pip-not-working-proxy-connection-aborted)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ProtocolError+Connection+aborted+BadStatusLine